# How to make git cvsimport checkout changes after some date?

Tags: git, cvs

I am using `git cvsimport` to work with a cvs server, and it works fine.
However, some very old projects have many commits and large files. It causes cvsimport to spend a long time checking out all commits and converting them to git format.

I `cvsimport` like this:

```
git cvsimport -v -a -d :pserver:qrtt1@localhost:/cvs cvsroot/my_module
```

Is it possible to select commits after some date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory you should be able to use the `-p` option of `git cvsimport` in conjunction with the `-d` option of `cvsps`. Here are the two relevant extracts from the man pages:

git cvsimport:

> -p < options-for-cvsps >
>
> Additional options for cvsps. The options -u and -A are implicit and should not be used here.
>
> If you need to pass multiple options, separate them with a comma.

cvsps:

> -d < date1 > -d < date2 >
>         if just one date specified, show revisions newer than date1.  If two dates specified, show revisions between two dates.

Unfortunately when I used it, cvsps complained about the date:

```
$ git cvsimport -v -d <cvsroot> -p "-d '2012/01/01 00:00:00'" <module>
Running cvsps...

bad usage: invalid argument -d '2012/01/01 00:00:00'

Usage: [...]

git cvsimport: fatal: cvsps reported error
```

Running `cvsps` by itself accepts the date though, so doing this as a two step process should work.

```
cvsps -d '2012/01/01 00:00:00' > patchset
git cvsimport -d <cvsroot> -P patchset <module>
```

You can examine the output of cvsps to confirm that it only has changes after the date you specified, before running the lengthy `cvsimport` command.

Comment: It exactly checkout the changes after the date. However, no any snapshot before the date. :D

Comment: Anyway, it is useful information. I can checkout the snapshot by date then apply the cvsimport. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you must seperate your cvsps arguments by comma:

```
git cvsimport -v -d <cvsroot> -p -d,'2012/01/01 00:00:00' <module>
```